# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, google-app-engine

***My Error Message when running my python scripts using a raspberry pi***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in (module)
    import appengineauth
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/google_appengine/appengineauth.py", line 30, in (module)
    auth_resp = urllib2.urlopen(auth_req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

***I'm able to access the website. Not too sure what is the actual problem.***

Comment: `HTTP Error 404: Not Found` means that the server couldn't find your URL resource. Although, you need to include your code!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using https://github.com/adafruit/Tweet-a-Watt/blob/master/appengineauth.py (you don't tell us where you got your `appengineauth.py` from, thus forcing us to guess), and its line

```
auth_uri = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin'
```

then you're likely running into the deprecation documented at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps , and I quote:

> Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated since April 20, 2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

I.e, the 404 you're getting would then be exactly the symptom the warning tells you about, now that ClientLogin has been removed, more than 3.5 years after the original deprecation warning.

Not sure how best to connect your Raspberry Pi to App Engine (or any other Google service requiring authentication) with OAuth 2.0 (since ClientLogin is not an option any more). http://guy.carpenter.id.au/gaugette/2012/11/06/using-google-oauth2-for-devices/ (written shortly after the deprecation but smartly avoiding reliance on the already-deprecated ClientLogin service) recommends an "OAuth2 for Devices" library and summarizes how to use it; I haven't tried that library myself (and I don't have a Raspberry Pi to try it on) but it does seem like a potentially fruitful avenue for you to explore.