# resolving deprecated ClientLogin for Installed Applications

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deprecated, http-error, google-client-login

Had a python script running ClientLogin for Installed Applications. It has since been deprecated. Need help in finding an alternate solution.

See link on my earlier post: [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560269/urllib2-httperror-http-error-404-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

From the deprecation warning on [ClientLogin for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps):

> Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated since April 20,
>   2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail
>   with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as
>   soon as possible.

This answer points to Google's auth choosing guide, in case you also want to look at other alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31053422/4495081